# How to organize wiki pages in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, administration, wiki

What is the best way to organize wiki pages on sharepoint 2007 ? I want to organize & categorize wiki articles in an orderly fashion, using article categories, for instance :

```
Animals
  |____ Fish
  |____ Mammals
       |____ Article on dogs
```

For this, I would like to be able to assign categories to specific articles, and create an automatically generated category page.
The only functionality I've seen so far that comes close to what I want is the use of tags. However, this does not allow for hierarchization of documents, as the tags `animals` and `animals, mammals` appear as 2 different tags in article classification.

Would you have any suggestion as to how to do this ?

EDIT: The blog site template offers a solution that comes quite close to what I want, through the implementation of out-of-the-box categories. Would there be a way to emulate this behaviour and apply it to wiki pages?